# Recommended Deletion on very short answer

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Albeit it received a bounty of +50, I do not consider this a good answer, since it does not explain anything but only provides a single line of code:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12098928

Am I mistaken here or is this just an unfortunate question for an audit?
I think, a code-answer should at least provide one or two sentences of explanation, otherwise it is quite worthless for most readers.

Edit: If it is such a good choice to down-vote questions, why isn't it possible to vote in that review queue at all? The reviewer is stuck with the options "Recommend deletion" or "Looks OK". Patrice and Cerbrus, please look a bit more thorough in the issues you comment about. Thank you.

Edit2: Reflecting the inputs I have gotten here, I am still puzzled. When I review an answer, I have the option "Looks OK", which has "This answer doesn't seem low quality" as a tooltip. But the answer seemed low-quality to me for a good reason (and that wasn't disputed by anyone yet). Why would this be the appropriate action then?

Comment: Deletion? A poor answer is downvoted. Not removed.... Unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 11):

Low quality answers should be downvoted, not delete-voted.

This audit is fine, and appears to have helped in reminding at least one user of the above.

Comment: As I stated in my edit above, "Looks OK" means, according to the tooltip, "This answer doesn't seem low-quality". So the delete option is the only feasible in my eyes.

Comment: @Ctx "Looks okay" means that the answer meets that the answer doesn't merit deletion, with the alternative being that it *does* merit deletion.  You choose to delete an answer that doesn't merit deletion.  That's wrong.  In the future when a post in the LQP queue doesn't merit deletion you should mark it as okay.

Comment: @Servy I think, the tooltip-explanation "This answer doesn't seem low-quality" is quite clear and cannot be interpreted otherwise. The queue is named "Low Quality Posts" and not "Not an answer Posts". Thus, the Low Quality of that Post made me recommend its deletion, since it "cannot be sanitized with reasonable effort". If this really was wrong, someone did a _very_ bad job in naming the queue, the buttons, and the explaining tooltips of the buttons, don't you agree?

Comment: @Ctx I do agree that the labeling of the items in the queue (and others) is poor, but that doesn't excuse you voting to delete an answer that doesn't merit deletion, as opposed to choosing to do nothing for an answer that doesn't merit any action.  If you were really that confused, you could have simply skipped the post, instead of trying to delete a post *you knew didn't merit deletion*.

Comment: @Servy Don't be arrogant here, reading several posts here on meta on this topic unearthes a quite vivid discussion on what is recommended for deletion and what not, I do not see a real consent.. Code-only answers are well suggested for deletion by several people. If you have the one and only authoritative source on how to handle such a case, please show it.

Comment: @Ctx On what grounds would a code only answer merit deletion?  If you feel that it merits deletion the burden is on *you* to show that it meets stated criteria for deletion, not on me to show that it doesn't.

Comment: Guys, take a step back, both of you. Don't let this degrade into a pointless debate.